# SSRS 2008 R2 Report prompting for login credentials

Tags: reporting-services

I developed a SSRS report and deployed that report to my staging server.

When I try to access the report it is always prompting for the login details. I noticed that the prompt is for the login information of datasource and not the report server.

My database server is different from the reportserver. Are there any configuration changes that need to be made to avoid the prompt ,as I have already mentioned those details in the datasource.

Can you anyone please help me in this.

There is a similar post [SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 R2 always show for login prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403136/sql-server-reporting-services-2008-r2-always-show-for-login-prompt) available in stackoverflow but it is referrring to report server I guess.

Please disregard my ignorance as I am new to SSRS.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work.

After some searching and tweaking it worked with the following process:
I clicked on the **Manage** option(select from the dropdown)of the report and selected the **Datasources** tab.

From the options displayed, I selected the option *Credentials stored securely in the report server* and provided the login credentials there and clicked Apply.

When I opened the report, it was not asking or prompting for the login anymore.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set credential for your data source as per your need.

Use Windows Authentication, that will not prompt for User Name and Password again and again.

[image]

Comment: What really got me was that you can also set username and password on the "general" tab in that dialog, but they have no effect(?) on the report connection...